# Text shrinking when cell selected in Material UI Table

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to figure out which piece of CSS is making the text shrink by a very tiny but noticeable amount in the cells when you select one of them

Here's a code sandbox. Just click on one of the cells to focus it and you'll see what I mean:-

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-virtualized-t2xkt

NOTE: when you select a cell, it replaces the plain div with a customised Material UI TextField

Which CSS property do I need to adjust to ensure that the text size and position stays uniform when the cell is focused or not focused?

Comment: Are you sure it's a change of font size? It seems maybe it's a change in padding

Comment: Yeh it could be change in padding. I just assumed it was font size

Comment: You were right it was the padding. Solved it by remove a pixel from the padding-top in the div within the table cell when not focused

Answer (score 0):

You were right it was the padding. Solved it by remove a pixel from the padding-top in the div within the table cell when not focused